# Create play buttons for facebook timeline like Spotify?

Tags: facebook, html, audio

I know Spotify is a Facebook partner so they get special privileges. But now that Facebook's OpenGraph API has been around for a while, is it possible to create an HTML5 player that works on people's timelines? I'm not even sure what it's called. Is it a ticker - with multiple audio links?

I want to supply a list of play buttons. When each play button is clicked, it needs to play the song and then play the next.

Since this is for a competing service, I don't want to use Spotify's API. Our company already uses a custom Flash-based player, but users have to click and load a Flash player which reduces click-through and doesn't work on non-flash based browsers.

Are there other companies that have non-flash players that embed into Facebook news feeds/timelines?

Answer (score 1):

The music Open Graph actions are restricted to Facebook white listed developers. There are several music services that have access to it, but they're all very well known (Pandora, I<3Radio, etc).

There is no form or application process to get white listed, you must be invited.